# Spring Profiles - JVM System Parameter in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I start a SpringBoot app, with this VM option:

[image]

but when I start the app. I see this on the console:

```
11:29:24.090 [main] DEBUG c.b.e.ServingWebContentApplication - Running with Spring Boot v2.3.7.RELEASE, Spring v5.2.12.RELEASE
11:29:24.090 [main] INFO  c.b.e.ServingWebContentApplication - The following profiles are active: dev
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using lowercase prod as a JVM flag or try using another method of setting different Spring profile. You can find a description of different methods for setting Spring Profile for example here [Baeldung Spring Profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)